# Why does ggplot annotate throw this warning: In is.na(x) : is.na() applied to non-(list or vector) of type 'expression'

Tags: r, ggplot2, annotate

I would like to annotate a ggplot plot with a simple equation.  The code below does it but it throws a warning about applying is.na():

```
library(ggplot2)
ggplot() +
  annotate(geom = "text", x = 1, y = 1, 
           label = expression(paste(beta, pi, "(1-" , pi, ")")),
           hjust = "left")
```

```
Warning message:
In is.na(x) : is.na() applied to non-(list or vector) of type 'expression'
```

What is the proper syntax to include the expression without the warning?

Why does this not make the warning go away?

```
suppressWarnings(
  ggplot() +
    annotate(geom = "text", x = 1, y = 1, 
             label = expression(paste(beta, pi, "(1-" , pi, ")")),
             hjust = "left")
)
```

I am using R version 4.0.2 with ggplot2 version 3.3.2

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The [annotate() function does not support expressions](https://github.com/tidyverse/ggplot2/issues/1548). you need to pass in a string and set `parse=TRUE`. You can do

```
  annotate(geom = "text", x = 1, y = 1, 
           label = 'paste(beta, pi, "(1-" , pi, ")")', parse=TRUE,
           hjust = "left")
```

Comment: The linked thread is interesting, but it is 5 years old and back then it seemed to have failed. the code by the OP does result in a nicely parsed expression, but just with warning. I am therefore not so sure if it is true that "annotate does not support expression".

Answer (score 7):

The way to run the code without warning, would be to pass the expression as a list and set `parse = TRUE`.

```r
library(ggplot2)
ggplot() +
  annotate(geom = "text", x = 1, y = 1, 
           label = list('paste(beta, pi, "(1-" , pi, ")")'),
           hjust = "left", parse = TRUE)
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2021-02-01 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

The warning is generated by trying to evaluate `is.na()` on an expression.

```r
is.na(expression(1 + 2))
#> Warning in is.na(expression(1 + 2)): is.na() applied to non-(list or vector) of
#> type 'expression'
#> [1] FALSE
```

In ggplot2, that sort of check happens in `ggplot2:::is_complete(expression(1 + 2))`, which is called in `ggplot2:::detect_missing`. I found out about this by setting `options(warn = 2)` and then using the `traceback()` to lead me to these functions.

Comment: thanks. That's the obscure function under the hood I was looking for :)