# ggplot annotate brakes axis

Tags: r, ggplot2, svg, annotate

I want to insert a text into my ggplot chart. The text got a subscript and a supersubscript like X[X} = 1,00*Y R^2 = 0,90. For that I used the function `paste(expression())` into `annotate(label=())`.

In the graphics pane the whole plot looks fine, like i needed. But if i want to save the plot into a svg using the svg.save function the plot missing the Axis and the annotate Text.

Without annotate the whole svg is fine. So I guess, the solution is fixing the `paste(expression())` function. But I didn't found a solution for that.

```
Data <- read.csv2("Data.csv", header = TRUE, sep = ";", dec = ",")
Data$ï..Date <- as.Date(Data$ï..Date, format = "%d.%m.%Y")

Gesamt_Plot1 <- ggplot() +
  geom_point(aes(X$EC,Y$BC), show.legend = FALSE, shape = 1, size = 1.5, na.rm = TRUE)+
  geom_abline(linetype = "dashed")+
  geom_segment(aes(x = 0.19,xend = 5.49, y = G1_slp*0.19,  yend = G1_slp*5.49), color = "black", size = 1.2, na.rm = TRUE)+
   annotate(geom="text", x = 4, y=6.4, parse = T, label=paste(expression(EBC~"="~"0,92*"*EC[TOR]~~R²~"="~"0,89")), color="black")+
   annotate(geom="text", x=0.1, y=7, label="a)", color="black")+
   labs(colour = "", x=expression(EC[TOR]~"in"~mu*g~m^-3), y=expression(EBC~"in"~mu*g~m^-3))+
    theme_bw()+
    theme(axis.text.y=element_text(size = 12), axis.text.x = element_text(size = 12),
        axis.title = element_text(size = 12), legend.position = "bottom", panel.grid.minor = element_blank())+
    scale_x_continuous(limit = c(0,7), 
                     breaks = c(0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7) 
    )+
    scale_y_continuous(limit = c(0,7), 
                     breaks = c(0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7)
    )
```

https://i.stack.imgur.com/9axhZ.png

Using R Version 4.0.5 and ggplot v3.3.3.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure I can reproduce your problem, but I think you should not be using `paste(expression(..))`, just use `expression(..)`. (Incidentally, I changed from your `R²` to `R^2` in the expression; I'm not certain if it's a UTF problem in my emacs/ess or not. Try it both ways if you prefer.)

```r
ggplot(mtcars, aes(mpg, disp)) +
  geom_point() +
  annotate(geom="text", x=20, y=60, 
           label=expression(EBC~"="~"0,92*"*EC[TOR]~~R^2~"="~"0,89"))
# Warning in is.na(x) :
#   is.na() applied to non-(list or vector) of type 'expression'
```

In the R graphics pane, I see

[image: ggplot2 graphics pane with expression annotation and axis labels]

Saving to svg:

```r
ggsave(filename="mt.svg")
# Warning in is.na(x) :
#   is.na() applied to non-(list or vector) of type 'expression'
```

which then shows

[image: ggplot2 saved as svg, viewed in a web browser]

---

Note: due to a long-standing ... bug/feature (?) in `ggplot2`, it warns about expressions. Granted, it's just a warning (and it plots fine), so it can be ignored. See [Why does ggplot annotate throw this warning: In is.na(x) : is.na() applied to non-(list or vector) of type 'expression'](https://stackoverflow.com/q/63095027/3358272). Another method is this:

```r
ggplot(mtcars, aes(mpg, disp)) +
  geom_point() +
  annotate(geom="text", x=20, y=60, 
           label=list('EBC~"="~"0,92*"*EC[TOR]~~R^2~"="~"0,89"'), 
           parse=TRUE) +
  labs(colour = "", x=expression(EC[TOR]~"in"~mu*g~m^-3), y=expression(EBC~"in"~mu*g~m^-3)) +
  theme_bw()
```

(using `list('...')` instead of `expression(...)`, and adding `parse=TRUE`). This produces the same effect.

Comment: If i do this i get a warning: In is.na(x) : is.na() applied to non-(list or vector) of type 'expression' and it still does not work.

Comment: And if i use the ggsave function i get: In grid.Call.graphics(C_text, as.graphicsAnnot(x$label), x$x, x$y,  :
  Metric information not available for this family/device

Comment: It's a known issue, see my edit (with no more warning ... though the warning was not breaking anything).

Comment: as for the error, perhaps https://www.mail-archive.com/r-devel@r-project.org/msg43261.html?

Comment: I don't know if the problem is with `ggsave` or base R's `svg`. Try `svg("mt.svg", ...)` (setting dims and such), then print your graphics (you won't see it in your graphics pane), then `dev.off()`. Again, not sure if that'll make a difference. It does not error for me. (win11, R-4.2.2, ggplot2-3.4.0)

Comment: Yes t-hanks to you, i removed the * and now the svg file works with both ways fine.

Comment: You may be able to use `%*%` instead of `*`, not sure if that's the sole issue. Glad it worked!